# cy.clear() not clearing input field properly - Cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress

When I perform

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear().type('random text');
```

If the text already has value lets say 'assd asd adsdsd' and I perform above command I get something similar to 'random textassd'

I also tried using

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear().should('have.value', '').type('random text');
```

It works some time and in other times it complains it does not equal to ' '.

And I am trying to do this in a each loop like below

```
const data = [
{selector:'#name', newValue: 'John'},
{selector:'#phone', newValue: '1234567'}
];
cy.wrap(data).each(field => {
cy.get(field.selector).clear().should('have.value', '').type(field.newValue);
cy.contains('Save').click();
cy.visit('/abc/sdd');
cy.get(field.selector).invoke('val').should('equal', field.newValue);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what happens when you split it into two separate statements? `cy.get('#fsp-name').clear()` and then `cy.get('#fsp-name').type("Random text")`

Comment: Try this cy.get('#fsp-name').click().clear().type('random text');

Comment: both did not work

Answer (score 21):

Tried the solutions provided above, but all did not help.
I've ended up using this:

```
cy.get('#my-input-element').focus().clear();
```

If that doesn't work, the not so happy workaround is:

```
cy.get('#my-input-element').invoke('val', '');
```

When .type somehow did not finish the given string (rare cases):

```
cy.get('#my-input-element').invoke('val', 'Some text here');
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem and It was related to focused and click related. I can suggest trying the following two option. I DON'T know it is right or wrong.

> cy.get('#fsp-name').click().clear().type('random text');

OR

> cy.get('#fsp-name').click().focused().clear().type('random text');

I was talking to the developer and according to him we are using MaterialUI and have some default component using focused and click event differently. After having both options resolved my problem

Answer (score 9):

`.clear()` is an alias of `.type('{selectall}{backspace}')` however depending upon the input field set up this would not work in all cases.

I solved this by using `.type('{selectall}{backspace}{selectall}{backspace}')` instead of the `.clear()`

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the cypress test runner is getting ahead of app initialization and some helpful article links below

https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/
https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/

As of now adding wait before clearing makes the test pass. Let me know if anyone has better solutions

Comment: Waiting before clearing doesn't help my situation. This is really odd as I've only ever once had a problem clearing and it was an elaborate code editor (monaco)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Cypress version 3.8.3 and I noticed that I have to invoke clear() sometimes two times in a row:

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear();
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem using Mui React with Cypress and when I called clear an ";" was added.

I've applied the same @Steven Vachon solution calling clear() function of cypress first.

Here my solution:

```
const clearInputElement = (input) => {
  const input2Search = input;
  cy.get(input2Search).clear();
  cy.get(input2Search).then(($elm) => {
    const event = new Event(input2Search, { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
    const input = $elm.get(0); // `as HTMLInputElement` for TypeScript
    input.value = "";
    input.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do clear manually via the DOM:

```
cy.get('input').then($elm => {
  const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
  const input = $elm.get(0); // `as HTMLInputElement` for TypeScript
  input.value = '';
  input.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I, too, faced a similar issue while using with react-ace editor. I wind up with

```
function typeContentOnSelectingExistingContent(elementId, content) {
  return cy.get(`#${elementId}`).type(`{selectAll}{selectAll}${content}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear({ force: true }).then(() => {
  cy.wait(3000)
  cy.get('#fsp-name').invoke('val', '').type(`${valueToBeTyped}{enter}`)
})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Official docs states that:

> It is unsafe to chain further commands that rely on the subject after .clear().

That's probably why the code in the original question didn't work, it was chaining clear and type commands:

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear().type('random text');
```

So, a simple alternative would be something like:

```
cy.get('#fsp-name').clear()
cy.get('#fsp-name').type('some text')
```

More about the clear command:

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear

Comment: The docs aren't clear. In that same page they have an example chaining the command.

Further, I have flaky tests that randomly fail, even when not using the chain.

Comment: @NunoLeong, the docs are clear. It is fine to chain commands, unless you do it AFTER the specific ".clear()" command. Therefore, if you want to use the clear() command, it should be the last one in the chain.

Comment: @Sverissimo: I believe what @nuno-leong was pointing out is that the docs currently include this example under [Examples](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear#Examples): `cy.get('textarea').clear().type('Hello, World')`

For what it's worth, I've tried your solution and it's still flaky in my environment. Using clear twice (e.g. `clear().clear().type(...)`) works, and using `.type('{selectall}{backspace}{selectall}{backspace}')` works, but not splitting the commands as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a number input with min set.

This field cannot be cleared. Therefore I used:

```js
cy.get("#my-field").click().type("{selectall}3")
```

In order to replace the existing value with the number 3.